# Dudas sobre javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo algundas dudas de Javascript.

1. Cual es el array que tiene las propiedades? creo haber leído que es diferente la creación entre `var array = [];` que `var array = new
   Array();`
2. Cuando uno crea un array de la forma `var array = new Array();` es necesario colocar algún numero en los parámetros?
3. Recuerdo haber aprendido a crear un array con elementos undefined , pero no recuerdo bien lo de las comas , era como `var array =
   [,,,,,,];` creo que aquí habrían 5 elementos `undefined`
4. Cuando estamos en una mismo función y al principio de la función colocan `var algo;` , luego por al medio de la función la definen como
   `algo = 2;` y luego al final como `algo = 4;` , al final que pasa con
   la  variable? el 2 se reemplazará por el 4 ? , se concatenan ? que
   sucede?  , porque si hago esto con un array (`array[array.length] =
   "Elemento6";`) , en este caso se le agrega un elemento , pero con las
   variables como va?

Comment: Hola eduardo. Varios puntos puedes verlos en la documentacion de javascript. y otros como el 4 son consideradas *basadas en opiniones* porque las practicas de cada usuario pueden ser distintas. Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes razón , disculpas por la pregunta 4 , y sí claramente he buscado lo que he preguntado aca , pero no he encontrado específicamente eso , solo las estructuras y definiciones , pero cosas así no, bueno seguiré buscando mientras tanto, gracias.

Comment: Hay una "cosa" que se llama Google y si eres un poquito autodidacta serías capaz de responder las dudas tu solito, es más, simplemente tienes que **crear un archivo .html y hacer las pruebas que quieras**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por pasos:

1-En principio no hay ninguna diferencia entre escribir `var array=[]` y `var array= new Array()` casi nunca, excepto en un caso, que es cuando la rellenes de números. Ejemplo:

```
var numeros = [45];
```

Esto crea una matriz con el número 45 en la posición 0.

```
var numeros= new Array(45);
```

esto te crea una matriz de 45 posiciones.

2- Cuando creas una matriz de esta manera `var array=new Array();` puedes crearla vacía por lo que puedes ir metiendo todos los objetos que quieras o puedes crearla con una longitud fija, pero esto último no es muy recomendable ya que cuando utilices el método .length de la matriz nunca va a ser 0 y esto puede dar muchos problemas a la hora de utilizarlo.

Las otras dos preguntas no voy a responderlas porque no estoy muy seguro de su uso y la última no podría contestarla correctamente ya que depende de la práctica de cada usuario.

Comment: Gracias , las demás ya las he resuelto :)